# Duplicate identifier error while creating a class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, data-structures

I'm trying to create a Linked List in Typescript, and I've created a INode interface, and a node class to start it off

```
interface INode<T> {
  data: T;
  next: INode<T> | null;
}

class Node<T> implements INode<T> {
  public data: T;
  public next: INode<T> | null;
  
  constructor(data: T) {
    this.data = data
    this.next = null
  }
}
```

The problem is: I'm getting a TS error that keeps saying:

```
Duplicate identifier "Node"
```

And based on the code I showed above, there's no duplicate identifier. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Node` conflicts with the abstract interface provide by the dom `Node` interface:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Either you need to name your class something else or remove `dom` from your compiler lib (e.g. `tsconfig.json`) if this is something you don't need.